# Ruby on Rails: Concerning rendering partials inside paginated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, pagination, partial-classes

I am really confused with how rendered paginated objects work.  Take this for example:

When I run

```
<%= render :partial => 'feeds/share_item', collection: @share_items %>
<%= will_paginate @share_items %>
```

I can go to `_share_item.html.erb` and inside of it I can do this...

```
<%= link_to "Delete", share_item, method: :delete, 
data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?" }, 
class: "btn-link", title: share_item.content %>
```

...and it will have the Delete link and all goes well.

But, while still in `_share_item.html.erb`, if I replace that with...

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/delete' %>
```

...I get this:

`undefined local variable or method 'share_item' for #<#<Class:0xaf0b888>:0xb15cb3c>`

**Why?**

I have been trying to resolve this issue for quite some time, because I have a lot of forms and links cluttered in my partial.  I want to be able to render said forms and links via *another* partial.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the variable share_item is empty, as it has not been supplied to the partial.
You would need to do something like this:

```
<% @share_items.each do |share_item| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/delete', :locals => { :share_item => share_item } %>
<% end %>
```

Or, the slightly more terse

```
<% @share_items.each do |share_item| %>
  <%= render 'shared/delete', share_item: share_item %>
<% end %>
```

Or, even better:

```
<%= render 'shared/delete',  collection: @share_items %>
```

You can find more info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer).

Comment: Hey, thanks alot.  You helped a 'doh' moment finally click! :p  Appreciate it. :)